# VB.Net align buttons in MessageBox

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

I've been searching but found nothing nowhere. I have a MessageBox in a WinForm where the buttons are YesNo but I also tried OkCancel.
Problem is I see buttons get aligned on the right. Is this normal? Shouldn't they be aligned center or is there a way to do that? I don't understand if the reason why I don't find anything about it is it's unchangeable or viceversa it's so default for buttons to be centered that no one talks about it.
I don't know what to try since usually I only use Ok button, rarely I went for YesNoCancel but I'm pretty sure those 3 were centered.

Comment: That's how the `MessageBox` class works. If you want different, you'll need to create your own custom form. Note that buttons aligned on the right is pretty much standard Windows layout. Centred buttons is more of a web thing and may also be standard on other OSes.

Comment: BTW, `YesNoCancel` aligns the buttons on the right too. Maybe you tested with text that wasn't wide enough to make that obvious.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thank you for your reply then. Too bad for me (I'm fan of centered layouts) but that's that...